# Re-sizing of slate in Drawing app

Tags: android

In my project, I have integrated google's Marker(Drawing) app, it is working fine. Now the requirement is, the slate size of the app should be fit to the image size as the user loads an image on it so that he should not draw anything besides the image.

for example, if I am the user, and I load an image into the drawing app and do some modifications to the image. The modifications should not go beyond the image. To do so the slate should be resized. how to do this?

**The Sample picture of current app**

[image: The Sample picture of current app]

**This is the Requirement**

[image: Requirement]

Please help me..